# Text Input Box misaligned in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm running into problems aligning an input text field, password text field  across all browsers. Any work around?

Here is my code for defining the textbox

```
<input cssClass="ui-widget ui-corner-all required" id="username" size="50" tabindex="1" path="username" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true" cssStyle="height:30px;padding-left: 3px;"/>
```

Now the text input field is working fine in IE and firefox but it is flowing out from the div in chrome....Any work around?

Comment: The problem appears to be you have no code. You don't need to do a work around, you just need to do work..

Comment: The code snippet wasn't indented and is now fixed, relax guys!

Comment: We need more HTML ... where is the div? Also, where are `cssClass` and `cssStyle` from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure in your CSS declarations that you either set your input fields to be 100% in width or less, so it's sized in relation to the container div.

Also, your HTML code has some errors when calling classes. It should be like this:

```
<input class="ui-widget ui-corner-all required" id="username" size="50" tabindex="1" autocomplete="false" style="height:30px;padding-left:3px;" />
```

Also, `path` and `htmlEscape` aren't valid attribute for input tags - see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp